# Pointer assigned to multiple variables

Tags: c, pointers

I am wondering what is the meaning of the following expression:

```
unsigned char *buff_p = txBuffer, hdrFlags, msgType;
```

Comment: Actually, it's one assignment only. The other two are just uninitialized variable declarations.

Comment: @KyleTrauberman: How can he use `unsigned char` in C#?

Comment: isn't the * incorrect for c#? `char* buff_p` would be fine, `char *buff_p` is not fine

Comment: @SimonHalsey Both of your examples compile for me; it's the `unsigned` that won't compile in C#.

Comment: Maybe I was wrong in my rollback.  Feel free to roll it back again.

Comment: @Servy can't get it compile. *p would do pointer indirection so * is an operator that needs to put the result somewhere, so can't be preceded by a type name

Comment: @SimonHalsey Not sure what to tell you.  I simply went and ran both through the compiler and they each worked just fine.

Comment: @Servy http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y31yhkeb%28v=vs.80%29.aspx says char *p is invalid in c#

Comment: @SimonHalsey according to that page `char *buff_p` is fine, `char *a, b` is fine, (and creates two char pointers, unlike C++ where it would create a pointer and a character) but `char *a, *b` is *invalid*, even though in C++ it would be valid and would create two pointers.

Answer (score 5):

That line declares three variables and assigns one of them.

It's just like

```
int a = 1, b, c;
```

Which is the same as

```
int b, c, a = 1;
```

To put it differently, **`=` has higher precedence than `,`.**

Comment: What are the types of the three variables?  Is it one char pointer and two characters, or three pointers?

Comment: They are all the same type, `unsigned char*`.

Comment: @Servy: Correction, in C# they would all be `char*`, but in c++ only the first is a pointer.

Comment: @Cemafor Yes, I knew that, which is why I asked.  It's not an easy question to answer.  In fact, I thought that might have been what the OP wanted to know, this implying that it should be included in this answer, but that doesn't seem to be the cased based on the OP's later comments.

Answer (score 0):

The line only does a single assignment and declares the other two variables.

```
unsigned char *buff_p = txBuffer, hdrFlags, msgType;
// buff_p points to txtBuffer
// other vars, they are of type char*
```

It's similar to `char one, two, three;` just with assignment for one of the declared variables (I didn't use pointers for this since there could be some added confusion).

Comment: You can't have unsigned char in c#. Also I believe the* is in the wrong place. if it were char* they would be char pointers, but with the space makes it invalid c#

Comment: @SimonHalsey someone changed the tag. It was correctly tagged as C/C++ a minute ago.

Comment: @SimonHalsey `char *buff_p;` compiles just fine for me.